# Animate CSS clip

Tags: css

I am trying to use CSS3 transitions to animate a CSS `clip` with no sucess. The image just clips without the transition.

What am I missing?

```
#clipped {
    position:absolute;
    width: auto;
    clip: rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
#clipped:hover {
    clip: rect(50px, 200px, 200px, 0);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/66CFD/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code works just fine. You just have to give it the correct "start" values, like so:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  clip: rect(10px, 100px, 200px, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

img:hover {
  clip: rect(80px, 200px, 250px, 50px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr86X.jpg">
```

Answer (score 6):

According to **[this site](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/)**, percentages in `rect` aren't supported.

If you know the size of the image, you can do this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/66CFD/1/)**

```
#clipped {
    clip: rect(0, 350px, 350px, 0);
}
```

Or instead of using `350px`, you could use much larger numbers to accommodate larger images. You may need to play around with the numbers to get an even animation.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first clip without unit, you cannot change the function which worked on the clip's changing;

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%); }

span:hover:before{ clip-path: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,0% 100%,0% 100%,); }
```