# CSS/JS scrolling glitch effect (performance)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I am trying to achieve a "crt-like" scrolling glitch effect using Javascript and CSS. I have come up with the following code which clones the content and applies `clip` to make it look like it scrolls while adding random horizontal offset.

```
function scanglitch() {
    var e = $('#wrapper').clone().appendTo('#glitchcontainer');
    var i = 0;
    e.css({"clip": "rect(" + i + "px,3830px," + (i + 15) + "px,0px)"});
    e.css("z-index",200);
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        e.css({"clip": "rect(" + i + "px,3830px," + (i + 15) + "px,0px)"});
        e.css({"left": Math.round(Math.random() * 10) + "px"});
        i+=4;
        if (i > window.innerHeight) {
            e.remove();
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 40);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hartger/9c63eb63/2/) (Click on the text to see the effect)

I am actually quite pleased with the effect, but the implementation is obviously a hack. As a result the performance is unacceptably low (chrome cpu usage spikes from 5% to 50% when the effect is triggered).

Could someone help me figure out a way to achieve this effect in a more elegant and less performance-heavy way?

UPDATE: 
I have implemented your suggestions: Using translate instead of left, scrolling with translate instead of a js loop, calculations outside of the css tag and using `requestAnimationFrame()`. The code is nicer and more predictable now, but the animations are still very taxing.
[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hartger/sbejwaph/)

Comment: Performance could be improved by not calculating anything inside the `.css()` method and using `translate` instead of `left` positioning. The `clip` property is deprecated by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delegate as much as possible to css transitions. So instead of moving the clip with js in the interval callback, transition it from top to bottom ([example of transitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056199/animate-css-clip)).

You could try something similar with the left property, there's no random easing function but maybe you could achieve something similar with one of the bounce functions. Maybe change the easing function with an interval that's less frequent than your current one.

Also, just by slowing the interval of your current solution you'd get visually ok results with less CPU usage.

Side-note: for a completely different route you can replicate your html in a canvas and apply some effects to that. Google has plenty of results for "[canvas glitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=canvas+glitch)".

Update: [here's my version of your latest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ku9cohz/)

I get about 10 % less cpu usage with it when comparing to yours. Key differences are:

- uses a timeout instead of `requestAnimationFrame`. `requestAnimationFrame` is meant to keep framerate high and the animation smooth but we don't need that for the random offsetting. Timeout is also better than an interval since the `loop` function is quaranteed to finish before next iteration starts.
- removed the transparent background, since transparency has a rendering cost

Comment: I redone the code to use transitions instead of using js. It sadly doesn't have much impact on performance. It seems the DOM-rendering is just very taxing, regardless of how it is called.

Comment: See my edit in my answer.   How are you measuring CPU usage?   I find little to no difference, and smoother animation using the  `requestAnimationFrame` method vs timeout vs transitions

Comment: I checked CPU usage from windows task manager and some individual execution times from chrome profiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `requestAnimationFrame` (it is available in [almost all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe)).  Seems to make a big difference in Chrome.

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9c63eb63/6/)</kbd>

**EDIT**

Here's a transition-only version, and while it doesn't even implement the jitter, it's useful for comparison.  Surprisingly(?) it shows about the same, if not more, CPU usage.  (You can check the Profile and Timeline tabs in Chrome)

<kbd>[**CSS3 Transition-Only JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbejwaph/1/)</kbd>

Here's [some information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance) about why that should be expected.  Essentially, CSS transitions and `requestAnimationFrame` work very similarly under the hood.

Comment: That's like only treating symptoms instead of the illness though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is indeed a more elegant solution. However performance is still an issue with this approach.

Comment: I think you are stuck with the performance.  See my edit and second fiddle.

Comment: I think you're right. I might look into a way to detect low framerate and disabling the animations when the client seems to struggle with them. Anyway, thank you very much for your help! (I sadly cannot mark both answers as the solution, but both were equally helpful so I picked the other one at random)